# Tag Analysis to know technology review by users

Tags: discussion, feature-request, data-explorer, statistics, experts

Is it possible to get analysis report on tags to know technology review. e.g.

1) Which technology has more questions (that has +5 vote up , atleast 1 from reputed person).

2) Which technology has more experts(stackoverflow by points) in the world.

3) Average time of problem resolutions for list of tags (by getting the time of acceptance of answer by reputed person)

Comment: No, I think it is not possible do to, with appealing to only tags. E.g. if we have tons of PHP tagged questions -- does it mean that PHP really hard, or that it is popular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As omnomnom said in a [comment to the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128621/tag-analysis-to-know-technology-review-by-users/128624#comment351182_128621), one can't really identify stuff from the available data.

### Experts

Experts? How, exactly, do we differentiate between experts and amateurs?

1. A lot of questions garner the same answer from experts and amateurs alike. A simple 'how can I do this with jQuery?' will not give any different answers. More verbose answers can be written by both people — maybe the amateur may do a bit of research, that's all.
2. It's not hard to (involuntarily) sound like an expert after being on this site for a while. I'm an amateur physics enthusiast-thingy. But I can still write long posts on Physics (on closer scrutiny you realize that I don't know what the hell im talking about :p )

### More questions != good questions

What does more questions tell you? It can tell you one of these:

- The topic is popular
- The topic requires a lot of thought
- The topic is vast

Omnom's example, PHP, falls into the third category. PHP is just a language which is very vast and confusing. A few bajillion built in functions! Not even nicely organised into packages like Java (though the manual is amazing). Weird stuff! `PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM`!  ......you get my point. On the other hand, [android](/questions/tagged/android) may have lots of entries because it's a popular platform (random claim, dunno)

### Fastest gun in the west

The time it takes for an answer/accept is meaningless. Lots of first answers are FGITW --the user posts first just to get  the first upvotes. Answer time varies wildly depending upon the type of question. So does accept time — and there's the issue of inactivish OPs.

Answer time can tell you how many people are <sub>^</sub><sup>pa</sup>trolling the tag in question, as well as the average question difficulty...maybe... There's also the fact that lots of questions are [plzsendtehcodez](/questions/tagged/plzsendtehcodez). And that lots of questions are vague. And other stuff — giving you a hopeless jumble..

### Answer to your question

Yes, use the [Data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com).